# Mongo how to update an element name

Tags: mongodb

I have a large collection in Mongo 4.2 with documents with a format like

```
"_id" : NumberLong(21),
"items" : {
    "BadLabel" : [ "A", "B", "C", "D"],
        "OtherLabel" : [ "E", "F" ]
    },
}
```

and certain documents have a 'BadLabel' that I would like to update to 'GoodLabel'.
I will have a variable length map of 'BadLabel's and 'GoodLabels' with different strings values.

I have tried to do

```
db.colln.updateMany( 
  { }, 
  { $rename: { "items.BadLabel": "items.GoodLabel" } } 
)
```

but that doesn't work.
Is there a way to update the label?

Comment: What was the error or output when you attempted that? Seems to work fine (on `6.0`) according to [this playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/OcgYmdt1GN6)

Comment: Thank you SO much, you are right, that does work, I was thrown off by other messages I'm getting. If I have a record with "items":null, then updateMany is giving me "cannot use the part (items of items.BadLabel) to traverse the element ({items: null}). I will add a filter for that

Comment: I'm also thrown off this because I actually don't have BadLabel but Bad Label (1), which contains space and parentheses. I'm now searching how to modify the rename clause to make it work.

Comment: Same approach works? [Example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/mXimWA79J_0)

Comment: What specifically isn't working? Are you getting an error? What is the result of the command? Are you running the command against the correct namespace? etc.

Comment: OK, after much troubleshooting I think I have this figured out. Please see https://mongoplayground.net/p/3wNqJs8Jv1L 
The issue is that once mongo encounters a null as the value of the element I'm updating, it won't change subsequent documents it finds. Seems like a mongo bug to me.

Comment: Are you sure the `null` is relevant or is it just a red herring? [This from the update documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/) seems relevant: "_By default, the `db.collection.update()` method updates a single document. Include the option `multi: true` to update all documents that match the query criteria._" Have you tried `updateMany()` or `multi:true`? [Demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/eR0ABGTYiCa)

Comment: It looks like you have `updateMany()` in the question originally. So I would basically just triple check everything once again

Comment: Yes, you are right again. The null is not the issue. In my own environment I'm doing updateMany() and it works. On the mongoplayground for whatever reason it only takes update() but not updateMany(). Somehow or another I think I'll get this to work. Thansk

Comment: It was the null entries that were making it not work.  
 With input collection this: [ { "_id": NumberLong(21), "items": null }, { "_id": NumberLong(23), "items": { "BadLabel (1)": [ "E", "F"] }, } ]. and update statement this: db.collection.update({}, { $rename: { "items.BadLabel (1)": "items.GoodLabel" } }, { multi: true }) it fails. In the playground it shows errors, but in my env it can fail silently. https://mongoplayground.net/p/bCkFEJYZKuH